# Merge Schema with int and double cannot be resolved when reading parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've got two parquet files, one contains an integer field `myField` and another contains a double field `myField`. When attempting to read both the files at once

```
val basePath = "/path/to/file/"
val fileWithInt = basePath + "intFile.snappy.parquet"
val fileWithDouble = basePath + "doubleFile.snappy.parquet"
val result = spark.sqlContext.read.option("mergeSchema", true).option("basePath", basePath).parquet(Seq(fileWithInt, fileWithDouble): _*).select("myField")
```

I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to merge fields 'myField' and 'myField'. Failed to merge incompatible data types IntegerType and DoubleType
```

When passing an explicit schema

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(new StructField("myField", IntegerType)))
val result = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(schema).option("mergeSchema", true).option("basePath", basePath).parquet(Seq(fileWithInt, fileWithDouble): _*).select("myField")
```

It fails with the following

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainDoubleDictionary
    at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToInt(Dictionary.java:48)
```

When casting up to a double

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(new StructField("myField", DoubleType)))
```

I get

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: org.apache.parquet.column.values.dictionary.PlainValuesDictionary$PlainIntegerDictionary
    at org.apache.parquet.column.Dictionary.decodeToDouble(Dictionary.java:60)
```

Does anyone know any ways around this problem other than reprocessing the source data.

Comment: You wont be able to merge different types. Can you try casting myField in one of Dataframes and then merge it ?

Comment: Possibly, but the files that contain doubles are a few over a rolling window of 100k. Don't want to pollute my code trying to search if these files exists, and then isolate them and cast before I proceed

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the number of files you are going to read you can use one of these two approachs:

This would be best for a smaller number of parquet files

```
def merge(spark: SparkSession, paths: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    paths.par.map {
      path =>
        spark.read.parquet(path).withColumn("myField", $"myField".cast(DoubleType))
    }.reduce(_.union(_))
  }
```

This approach will be better to process a large number of files since it will keep lineage short

```
def merge2(spark: SparkSession, paths: Seq[String]): DataFrame = {
    import spark.implicits._

    spark.sparkContext.union(paths.par.map {
      path =>
        spark.read.parquet(path).withColumn("myField", $"myField".cast(DoubleType)).as[Double].rdd
    }.toList).toDF
  }
```